# How to execute a SQL Script on Redshift Cluster via AWS Java API

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a script with 3500+ sql statements - some single-line statements and some multi-line statements.  it's too slow to run all these statements via JDBC...about 30 minutes too slow!  I'm hoping to find a way that I can hand off the script to the Redshift cluster to run on the cluster and that it would run much faster.  Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this via the Java AWS SDK or otherwise?  Thanks!

To add a little more color:  I'm looking to have some integration tests create their own database, schemas, and tables, then run the tests, then tear down the database.  Maybe I'm asking too much of Redshift.  Dunno.  Ordinarily, I'd do this in postgres running in a docker container, but we're using a lot of redshift specific functionality, like field encoding and external tables, etc, so none of that works in Postgres.

Using psql, from the command line, to run the script takes 25+ minutes.  When I run against a local postgres running in a docker container, having removed all the redshift specific stuff from the script, it runs in a couple of seconds.  I don't expect it to necessarily run in seconds on redshift, but 25+ minutes is unacceptable.

```
+ psql -A -E -q -t --file=src/test/resources/baseline/redshift/namsdev/2023-09-25/redshiftdump.rms.sql

real    25m44.212s
user    0m0.350s
sys     0m0.315s
```

Answer (score 0):

Too slow per what?  Are you running on a Lambda?

You may be looking for Redshift Data API - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift-data/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

This lets you make API calls to submit queries to Redshift and check back later on status.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @Bill Weiner, but I'm looking to do this in unit/integration tests.  I'd like each test to create it's own database, run the tests, and then tear down after itself.  Submitting queries to redshift and then checking back later during an integration test is probably not going to fly.  Maybe I'm asking too much of Redshift.  Dunno.

Comment: please see my updates above.

Comment: There are lots of layers here so let me take a stab at what is limiting you.  The number of commands you are running and they time they complete in along with the speed of local execution suggests that the network connection and its handshakes are the problem.  I think this is where you are leaning as well.  Send SQL, compile SQL, return - over and over.  The best way to speed this up would be to execute SQL commands in parallel.  The sets of SQL will need to be independent but I expect with so many commands a few independent sets should exist.